# adding sub-margins to pandas crosstab

Tags: python, pivot-table, margins

I'm using the following crosstab function:

```
def Evolution(indicators):
    for indicator in indicators:
        pivot = pd.crosstab(index=[df['modality'], df['quarter'], df['gender']], 
        columns= df['level'], margins=True).fillna(
            0).drop(['All'], axis=0).reset_index()
        pivot.to_excel(indicator + '.xlsx')
```

to get the following results:
[image: Actual output]

For each disaggregation by gender, I want to add sub-margins like the below in yellow:

[image: Desired output]

Comment: Could you please add a sample of your data to your question (as text, not as image) to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use stack-unstack & do the subtotal; follow below code;

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"modality":['modality']*8,
                   "quarter":[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4],
                  "gender":["F","M","F","M","F","M","F","M"],
                  "level1":[2,4,1,6,4,3,7,9],
                  "level2":[3,5,8,9,0,9,8,0]})

cnt=0
for col in ["level1","level2"]:
    if cnt == 0:
        df_temp = df.groupby(['modality', 'quarter', 'gender'])[col].sum().unstack(level=['quarter', 'gender'])
        df_temp = df_temp.assign(All=df_temp.sum(1))
        df_temp = df_temp.stack(level='quarter')
        df_temp = df_temp.assign(All=df_temp.sum(1))
        df_temp = df_temp.stack(level='gender')
        df_temp = pd.DataFrame(df_temp).reset_index()
        df_temp.rename(columns={0:col}, inplace=True)
        df_temp = df_temp[df_temp["quarter"] != "All"]
        df_final = df_temp.copy()
        cnt = 1
    else:
        df_temp = df.groupby(['modality', 'quarter', 'gender'])[col].sum().unstack(level=['quarter', 'gender'])
        df_temp = df_temp.assign(All=df_temp.sum(1))
        df_temp = df_temp.stack(level='quarter')
        df_temp = df_temp.assign(All=df_temp.sum(1))
        df_temp = df_temp.stack(level='gender')
        df_temp = pd.DataFrame(df_temp).reset_index()
        df_temp.rename(columns={0:col}, inplace=True)
        df_temp = df_temp[df_temp["quarter"] != "All"]
        df_final[col] = df_temp[col]
```

Output of df_final;

[image]

Comment: You may want to read the question again. This is not what the OP is searching for.

Comment: Yes.. I misread the question... Made the changes in my answer accordingly... Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You want to groupby `modality`, `quarter`, `gender` and sum the values to get a intermediate dataframe. Then concat it back to the original df and sort the index.

Used Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'modality' : ['modality1']*15,
    'quarter' : ['2018 Q1', '2018 Q1', '2018 Q2', '2018 Q2', '2018 Q3', '2018 Q3', '2018 Q4', '2018 Q4', '2019 Q1', '2019 Q1', '2019 Q2', '2019 Q2', '2019 Q4', '2019 Q4', '2020 Q1'],
    'gender' : ['Female', 'Male']*7 + ['Female'],
    'level1' : [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,24,12,33,3,12,6],
    'level2' : [16,35,17,46,9,20,16,35,28,31,33,31,15,25,33],
    'level3' : [0,0,0,2,1,1,0,4,1,0,0,1,0,0,1],
    'level4' : [29,144,21,142,21,150,24,162,30,113,31,107,24,36,40]
})
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# get a Multilevel Index with 3 levels
df = df.set_index(['modality', 'quarter', 'gender'])

# build the sum for each group
tmp = df.groupby(['modality', 'quarter']).sum()

# extend the Index by 1 level with constant 'All' values (this is also a 3 level index now)
tmp.index = [tmp.index.get_level_values(0),
             tmp.index.get_level_values(1),
             np.repeat('All', len(tmp))]
print(tmp)
```

```
                       level1  level2  level3  level4
modality  quarter                                    
modality1 2018 Q1 All       0      51       0     173
          2018 Q2 All       0      63       2     163
          2018 Q3 All       0      29       2     171
          2018 Q4 All       0      51       4     186
          2019 Q1 All      33      59       1     143
          2019 Q2 All      45      64       1     138
          2019 Q4 All      15      40       0      60
          2020 Q1 All       6      33       1      40
```

```
# concat df and tmp and sort by the levels to queue each 'All' row to their group (level 2 in descending order)
out = (
    pd.concat([df, tmp])
    .sort_index(level=[0,1,2], ascending=[True, True, False])
    .reset_index())
print(out)
```

Output:

```
     modality  quarter  gender  level1  level2  level3  level4
0   modality1  2018 Q1    Male       0      35       0     144
1   modality1  2018 Q1  Female       0      16       0      29
2   modality1  2018 Q1     All       0      51       0     173
3   modality1  2018 Q2    Male       0      46       2     142
4   modality1  2018 Q2  Female       0      17       0      21
5   modality1  2018 Q2     All       0      63       2     163
6   modality1  2018 Q3    Male       0      20       1     150
7   modality1  2018 Q3  Female       0       9       1      21
8   modality1  2018 Q3     All       0      29       2     171
9   modality1  2018 Q4    Male       0      35       4     162
10  modality1  2018 Q4  Female       0      16       0      24
11  modality1  2018 Q4     All       0      51       4     186
12  modality1  2019 Q1    Male      24      31       0     113
13  modality1  2019 Q1  Female       9      28       1      30
14  modality1  2019 Q1     All      33      59       1     143
15  modality1  2019 Q2    Male      33      31       1     107
16  modality1  2019 Q2  Female      12      33       0      31
17  modality1  2019 Q2     All      45      64       1     138
18  modality1  2019 Q4    Male      12      25       0      36
19  modality1  2019 Q4  Female       3      15       0      24
20  modality1  2019 Q4     All      15      40       0      60
21  modality1  2020 Q1  Female       6      33       1      40
22  modality1  2020 Q1     All       6      33       1      40
```